# Can a Warlock become a lich?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

I'm going to play a Warlock character starting at 3rd level. I want to know if he can become a lich. If this is possible, is there something that I must do before he can become a lich,  such as take some spells or skills? I want to change characters after he becomes a lich, so I only need to worry about the the pre-conditions. The DM gave no limits.

Comment: Very similar to [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/71187/ways-to-become-lich-ish/71197). I think the questions are different enough to be kept open though.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Deciding how a lich is created is the DM's job, as the game does not provide the answer (and arguably it should depend on the setting anyway). Your DM sounds cooperative, so I'm sure you can come up with something creative and awesome together.

Comment: The only other piece I'd consider as part of this answer is that the monster description of the lich does say it is a "wizard." There aren't really RAW for how one becomes a lich, but the monster description may be the closest we can offer the questioner.

Comment: Curse of Strahd provides a RAW method of becoming a lich, and it requires the beneficiary to be capable of casting 9th-level wizard spells.  This is far from the only way to become one, though.

Comment: @r256 That would fall under “depends on the setting”, not what I would call “RAW”. :)

Answer (score 5):

According to one of the items in 5e's DMG called the Book of Vile Darkness, there is a spell that one can learn in there to become a lich or a death knight, but only wizards can learn spells so your DM may (or may not) homebrew a system for Warlocks to become liches.

Answer (score 2):

In past editions, clerics could also become liches, and I see no reason why a DM couldn't houserule a ritual that a Warlock could learn to become one as well. Hell, if it was a ritual any spellcaster could potentially do it, which opens up a lot of conceptual space for a Lich.

Comment: It doesn't really affect the answer but surely if it was a ritual, anyone (of any class) with the 'Ritual Caster' feat could do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Lich Patron then the Lich already has the spell that unbinds your soul then binds it to a phylactery as well as the potion needed. No reason why it can't cast the spell on someone else. But you'll still have the Warlock spell system.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Warlocks have a pact feature called Pact of the Book, which allows you to take an invocation called Book of Ancient Secrets that allows to ritual cast any type of ritual spell inside of the book, and allows you to add any type of ritual spell into the book. So yes you can, you just have to add said spell into your book and you are good to go.

Comment: What part of this leads to becoming a Lich? You've described some some mechanics but not followed through in conveying how that leads to Lichdom. Is there a "become a Lich" ritual spell in that book? Is there one generally available that must be added into it first? You need to finish joining the dots here; Stack doesn't very well handle "and I leave it to the reader to fill in the solution"-type answers.