# What are the effects of being a lich?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead

I have read a few questions about PCs becoming a lich and how to do it.

Now I was wondering if there is any information about what changes mechanically for a PC when turning in a lich. Are there stat blocks for it or should a DM homebrew these kind of things?

Comment: Have you read Monster Manual?

Comment: @AntiDrondert I have seen the lich entry in the monster manual but that says nothing about the effect of a player becoming a lich and what effect it would have. you cant just copy the lich stat block and make that your character sheet, it would be to strong

Comment: @kviiri Have you playerd/read *Curse of Strahd* adventure?

Comment: @AntiDrondert i have not

Comment: Related: [Can a PC be a lich?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109138/can-a-pc-be-a-lich)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### PC transforms into a lich

The only source I could find that directly addresses PC actualy *becoming* a lich is *Curse of Strahd* adventure.
This can be found at the end of Chapter 13, pg. 196:

> When the beneficiary drinks the potion, he or she instantly transforms into a **[lich](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/lich)** under the Dungeon Master's control (use the stat block in the *Monster Manual*, altering the lich's prepared spells as desired).