# Lichdom for Warlocks

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, warlock, undead

In our next campaign, I will play a fiend warlock. 
I have made a pact with a powerful devil. He will get my soul once I die. In exchange, he gave me a portion of his power.
Since the deal, I have matured. I have found religion, and regret the pact. 
Thus, I want to avoid dying at all cost.
My endgoal would be to become a lich (or achieve immortality another way).

Is this even possible for warlocks, or can only wizards become liches? I have read conflicting information online...
How do I go about becoming a lich? Are there fixed rules and requirements, or does my DM have to make it up?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why and we'll see what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Here are two other related posts that you might find helpful: "[Ways to become Lich-ish](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71187)" and "[Can a PC be a lich?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109138)"