# How do you become a lich and what happens when you become one?

Tags: dnd-5e, player-characters

So I was researching the Book of Vile Darkness. It says in it that it contains the information in which you could become a lich. How would you become one and what happens when you do?

Comment: I've marked your question as a dupe because I think it has been asked before. This isn't a bad thing as this question might help others find that one. If that question doesn't answer it for you, please clarify for us how and why and we'll we what needs to be done to help you.

Comment: Various related questions (do any of these answer your own question?): "[Can a PC be a lich?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/109138)" and "[Ways to become Lich-ish](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71187)" and "[Can a Warlock become a lich?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/59196)" and "[Ways to become Lich-ish](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/71187)"

Comment: Thank you!. I just needed an answer so thank you for linking them.